# ImportError: cannot import name 'objc' from 'AppKit'. How do I debug a text-to-speech error in Python (pyttsx3)?

Tags: python, appkit, pyttsx3, nsspeechrecognizer

The error I'm getting is:

File "/*********************************/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyttsx3/drivers/nsss.py", line 4, in 
from AppKit import NSSpeechSynthesizer, objc
ImportError: cannot import name 'objc' from 'AppKit'

The relevant code of my nsss file is:

```
from Foundation import NSObject

from AppKit import NSSpeechSynthesizer, objc

from PyObjCTools import AppHelper



def buildDriver(proxy):

    return NSSpeechDriver.alloc().initWithProxy(proxy)


class NSSpeechDriver(NSObject):
    @objc.python_method
    def initWithProxy(self, proxy):
        self = super(NSSpeechDriver, self).init()
        if self:
            self._proxy = proxy
            self._tts = NSSpeechSynthesizer.alloc().initWithVoice_(None)
            self._tts.setDelegate_(self)
            # default rate
            self._tts.setRate_(200)
            self._completed = True
        return self
```

As a result of this error, I can't the text-to-speech library the way I want to.

I tried downloading obj through "pip install" and attempted at editing how appkit/nssspeech is imported. I also tried asking ChatGPT multiple times--all attempts failed.

I'd really appreciate it if anyone could help me troubleshoot this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are trying to import `objc from AppKit`, which doesn't exist

You should instead do `import objc`.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I tried changing that, and I'm still getting: "ImportError: cannot import name 'objc' from 'PyObjCTools' (unknown location)." Is there a way I can fix this?

Comment: How did you import it? Looks like you were trying to do `from PyObjCTools import objc`. Do literally as I did in my answer. `import objc`

Comment: `import abc
from Foundation import NSObject
from AppKit import NSSpeechSynthesizer
import objc
from PyObjCTools import AppHelper` was what I did.  This time I'm getting something new, "AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'init'
sys:1: UninitializedDeallocWarning: leaking an uninitialized object of type NSSpeechDriver"